# Using Scanner in other class rather than main class

Tags: java, class

I am using netbeans as my IDE. The program isn't compiling.

I don't understand where I have made mistakes:

```
package javaapplication20;

/**
*
* @author HAYES
*/
public class JavaApplication20 {

   /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        maximumfinder m = new maximumfinder();
        m.determinemaximum();
    }
}
```

My `maximumfinder` class:

```
package javaapplication20;

/**
 *
 * @author HAYES
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class maximumfinder {

    public void determinemaximum()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double num1 = input.nextDouble();
        double num2 = input.nextDouble();
        double num3 = input.nextDouble();

        double result = maximum(num1, num2, num3);

        System.out.println("result is:" + result);
    }

    public double maximum(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double maxvalue = x;

        if (y > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = y;

        if (z > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = z;

        return maxvalue;
    }
}
```

When I am not using `Scanner` in `main()`, it is not taking input from the user. Why is that? It's also an example from Deitel's book.

Comment: `1. The program isn't compiling. 2.i don't understand where i have made mistakes` - 1. format your question to make it mor readable, 2. post which compiler errors you get. 3. Did you debug your code/do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: If the both the classes are public and If they locate in same file, you will get a error. You should have only one Public class and file name should be matching with the Public class name. Otherwise, you can write them in two Files. Class per file.

Comment: yes i have debugged the code.

Comment: omkar sirra there isn't any error showing in IDE

Answer (score 1):

code looks perfect, i tried it. it's working fine.
there's no `System.out.println()` before `Scanner`, so you did not see any message in console and then you have to enter 3 numbers and you'll get maximum number.

`System.out.println("please enter three numbers :");`

Enter Above line before below code,so you can see message in console before entering the number

```
    double num1 = input.nextDouble();
    double num2 = input.nextDouble();
    double num3 = input.nextDouble();
```